# How do I pass a pattern to the compile() method when the raw string uses a combo of the special characters, such as inequalities (<= & >=)?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, data-analysis

How do I get my re.compile function to identify inequalities that combine special characters ( >= & <=) ? It only picks up the equal sign and I need both symbols together.

Code:

```
constraint_re = re.compile(r"(?P<prefix>['~','^','>=','<='])?(?P<major>\d+)(\.(?P<minor>(\d+|x)))?(\.(?P<patch>(\d+|x)))?(-.*)?")

testmatch = constraint_re.search("~0.0.2")
testmatch.group("prefix")
```

Output:

```
'~'
```

Test code for <=

```
testmatch_1 = constraint_re.search("<=0.0.2")
testmatch_1.group("prefix")
```

Output

```
'='
```

Comment: How about this: ```(?P<prefix>[~^]|(?:[<>]?=?))```. Matches an empty string though. Also, your regex didn't include ```<```

Comment: I am trying to use this code for a similar expression where I want the regex pattern to identify values in a column that use two inequalities, for example: >=0.9.8 <0.9.10    My code looks like this ```inequality_to_tilde = re.compile(r"(?P<inequality_to_tilde>((?:[>]?=?)(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\s(?:[>]?=?)(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)))?") ``` but the error 'no such group' comes up. What am I missing?